# Search and replace exact pattern ignoring substring matches in vim

Tags: vim

There are 1000s of occurrences of `first` and `firstnum` in the file.

I want to search for all occurrences of `first` and replace them with `firstnum`.

However, `firstnum` occurrences shouldn't become `firstnumnum`

Is there any way to do it with `%s` ?

Like

```
:%s/first/firstnum/gc
```

But I don't want to use `gc`, because in which case I will have to confirm for 1000s of matches of `first`.

Answer (score 4):

Use 'word boundaries':

```
:%s/\<first\>/firstnum/g
```

From `:help \<`:

> `\<`    Matches the beginning of a word: The next char is the first char of a
> word.  The 'iskeyword' option specifies what is a word character.

and from `:help \>`:

> `\>`    Matches the end of a word: The previous char is the last char of a
> word.  The 'iskeyword' option specifies what is a word character.

So this will not match any words that merely contain the string 'first', but
only the word 'first' if it's surrounded by white-space, or parentheses, or a
white space on one end and a period right after etc. etc.

##### Bonus

This one's so useful I have a mapping for it (inspired by the default
<kbd>*</kbd> functionality: search forward for word under the cursor, see
`:help *`):

```
" substitute word under the cursor
nnoremap <LEADER>* :%s/\<<C-r><C-w>\>/
```

Then with the cursor on the word 'first', pressing <kbd>LEADER</kbd> +
<kbd>*</kbd> will put you on the command line pre-populated with:
`:%s/\<first\>/`